# NavigationLink button activates on whole screen in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I tried creating a NavigationLink button using Rectangle(), like this:

```
NavigationView (content:{

    ZStack{

        NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)){ 

                Rectangle() 
                    .frame(maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 183) 
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.11, green: 0.11, blue: 0.11, opacity: 0.5)) 
                    .position(.init(x: 160, y: 170.0))
                }
        }
    })
```

It displays correctly but it gets activated even outside of the button.

I tried changing the ZStack to HStack but the button still reacted on whole width of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting `.position` on the `Rectangle` but not the `NavigationLink`, the whole navigation link has to expand, so that its label, the rectangle, can be at (160, 170.0).

You should put `frame` and `position` on the `NavigationLink`, not the rectangle:

```
// NavigationView is deprecated - I've changed it to a NavigationStack
NavigationStack {
    ZStack{
        NavigationLink {
            SomeView()
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        } label: {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.11, green: 0.11, blue: 0.11, opacity: 0.5))
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 183)
        .position(x: 160, y: 170.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting the position of the Rectangle instead of the NavigationLink. In this case NavigationLink takes up all the available space and Rectangle is then placed on top of it. If you move the .position modifier out on the NavigationLink, this solves the problem.

```
NavigationView (content:{
    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)){
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 300, height: 183)
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.11, green: 0.11, blue: 0.11, opacity: 0.5))
        }
        .position(.init(x: 160, y: 170.0))
})
```